# Failed to prepare device for development

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, macos-monterey

I'm encountering a well know problem in the Xcode environment. But I don't know how to procede.

I update my MacBook Air m1 to `Monterey 12.3.1` then this message appears every time I try to run my application on my `iPhone X 15.4.1`.

[image: Problem]

I have `Xcode 13.2` but the problem began when i upgraded macOs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the software on your phone to the latest and the xcode to the latest versions

Comment: You are right. Because my version of `xcode` is `13.2` and it does not support my `iOS` version which is `15.4.1`. But there is a way to update `xcode` without reinstalling all? Because I downloaded it from the official releases page and not from the App Store.

Comment: No, xcode is just from app store update